# Modernizr - touch || hover for an image link

Tags: jquery, touch, modernizr

I am trying to tackle mobile and desktop with this function. Is there a way to take this script I'm using for hover and add an `or` operator for Modernizr to see if it detects the touch functionality, and if not, use hover? Hoping someone can help clarify this for me.

```
$(function() {
        $('ul.recent-widget li').hover(function(){
            $(this).find('img').animate({top:'182px'},{duration:500});
        }, function(){
            $(this).find('img').animate({top:'0px'},{duration:500});
        });
    });
```

Here's an example of if working for the desktop http://jsfiddle.net/chris_s/dcq2F

Comment: What's the problem with just having the hover code on both platforms? On mobile it'll just never run because it's impossible to "hover" without a constant cursor.

Comment: so literally run it twice, but the mobile function `if(Modernizr.touch) { ... }`? Won't this code run twice on desktop making it not as efficient as possible?

Comment: Would `Modernizr.touch` be `true` on a desktop? If not, what's the problem? If so ... huh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Modernizr, you certainly could set up a conditional, as you infer in the comments above, which would only run one function or the other:

```
if ( Modernizr.touch ) {
   // click or bind to touchstart, touchmove, etc
} else {
   // hover (like your animation example)
}
```

Regarding performance, you might also consider using a default css transition or animation, then leverage `!Modernizr.csstransitions`, on that hover function, for example.

Of course, with mobile being such a moving target, [there](http://blog.grayghostvisuals.com/modernizr/conditionally-loading-resources/) [are](http://daneden.me/2011/12/putting-up-with-androids-bullshit/) [caveats](http://css-tricks.com/browser-detection-is-bad/) with any one solution. Perhaps combo test on several criteria (screen size, feature detection, polyfills, etc.) and go with what works best for your situation.